# ErrorInvalidIdMalformed while accessing message through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access message using graph API with the following URL.

```
 _graphAPIEndpoint = Uri.EscapeUriString("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/8577e5c2-3d1b-4882-b930-02de5ad18809@CH1GMEHUB07.gme.gbl");
```

However, I keep getting the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
    "message": "Id is malformed.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "8b2d8f88-ff5b-44f7-bb71-8867a03136b7",
      "date": "2018-06-07T18:00:32"
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Message ID value should be taken from id field passed by Graph API. To use message ID, following query works:

_graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq ''"